# Java call procedure oracle plsql return no data but in plsql return data

Tags: java, oracle, function, plsql, procedure

I have a function plsql, run function in plsql return cursor have data But i call this function in java problem return resultset falase Help me handling problem this

```
enter code here
```

This function plsql

```
FUNCTION get_canh_bao(
        p_toolid        in  varchar2)
      RETURN  sys_refcursor IS

        s           varchar2(4000);
        ptype       varchar2(1000);
        pday        varchar2(1000);
        psql        varchar2(1000);
        pcreate     varchar2(1000);
        re          sys_refcursor;
        pwhere      varchar2(1000);
    BEGIN
    --
        pwhere := '';
        s := 'select b.TYPE_REPORT, b.DAY_NHAPLIEU, a.sql_cmd, a.name_createdate'
            ||' from cpcdata.tbl_config_nhaplieu a'
            ||' left join cpcdata.tbl_mainmenu b'
            ||' on a.tool_id = b.ID '
            ||' where b.show_all = 0 and b.flag = 1 and b.ID = :toolid';
        execute immediate s INTO ptype, pday, psql, pcreate using p_toolid;
                -- Tinh ngay canh bao
                if (INSTR(psql,'where') > 0 ) then
                    pwhere := ' and ';
                else
                    pwhere := ' where ';
                end if;
                s := psql ||pwhere||pcreate||' between :aDate AND :bDate';
                CASE
                    WHEN ptype = 'day'    THEN
                        s := psql ||pwhere|| ' to_char('||pcreate||',''dd/mm/yyyy'') = to_char(sysdate - '||pday||',''dd/mm/yyyy'')';
                        open re for s;
                    WHEN ptype = 'week'   THEN
                        open re for s USING TRUNC (sysdate, 'iw'), TRUNC(sysdate, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400- pday;
                    WHEN ptype = 'month'  THEN
                        open re for s USING TRUNC (sysdate, 'mm'), to_date(LAST_DAY(TRUNC (sysdate, 'mm')) + 1 - 1/86400 - pday,'dd/mm/yyyy');
                    WHEN ptype = 'quy'    THEN
                        open re for s USING TRUNC (sysdate, 'Q'), to_date(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Q'),3)- 1 - pday, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
                    WHEN ptype = 'year'   THEN
                        open re for s USING TRUNC (sysdate , 'YEAR'), to_date(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC (SYSDATE,'YEAR'),12) - 1 - pday, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
                    ELSE return null;
                END CASE;
        dbms_output.put_line(''||s);
        RETURN re ;
        exception when others then
            declare
                s_err       varchar2(2000);
                str         varchar(2000);
                c_err       sys_refcursor;
            begin
                s_err := 'loi khi lay du lieu '|| sqlerrm;
                str := 'select '||s_err||' from dual';
                open c_err for str;
                return c_err;
            end;
    END;
```

This is code java

```
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  Connection conn =
      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:**:**",
                                  "***", "***");
  System.out.println("Connect db success ! ");
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            String sql = "{? = call get_canh_bao(?)}";
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cs.setString(2, "502");
            cs.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject(1);
            System.out.println("------------ResultSet---------------"+rs.next());
            while (rs.next()) {

              System.out.println("a");
              String[] str =
              {"1" };
              arr.add(str);
            }

  System.out.println("size="+arr.size());
```

Result when run code in java

```
Connect db success ! 
------------ResultSet---------------false
size=0
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you are in the System.out.println advancing to the first record and in the while loop you take the next record - if any.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely caused by one of the date conversions that uses an implicit date format.

Oracle does not have a "default" date format, the date format is always dependent on the client.  Your Java client and database IDE likely have different defaults.

But *don't* fix the code by changing the client settings.  Instead, clean up the date functions and remove all date to character conversions.

In general, when working with dates, `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` should almost always be avoided.  If a date needs to be manipulated, there is almost surely a date function
 that does not require a conversion.  And dates should always be stored as dates, so you should not need to convert back and forth from the table.

The biggest problem is probably this:

```
    pcreate     varchar2(1000);
```

Change that to a date.  If for some reason `a.name_createdate` is a string, then at least make the conversion explicit.

Comment: thanks you, but pcreate of table type varchar. Also I things problem not this here.

Comment: In procedure function plsql : when run function return data

Answer (score 0):

You're populating `pcreate` (a string) from `tbl_config_nhaplieu.name_createdate` without specifying a format, so (assuming it is a `date` column) it is possible that the format could be different within the Java client environment, e.g. if it defaults to `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd-mon-yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Later you compare it directly to dates:

```
s := psql || pwhere || pcreate || ' between :aDate and :bDate';
```

but without quoting, so you'll get a query like this:

```
where 01/02/2016 between :aDate and nDate
```

Elsewhere you convert it back to a date assuming `dd/mm/yyyy` format (which you didn't specify when you encoded it as a string earlier, so there's no reason it should match that format):

```
s := psql || pwhere || ' to_char(' || pcreate || ',''dd/mm/yyyy'') = to_char(sysdate - ' || pday || ',''dd/mm/yyyy'')';
```

but it's not quoted there either, so you'll get something like this:

```
where to_char(01/02/2016,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate - 3,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

which will fail.

Then there's this:

```
to_date(last_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')) + 1 - 1 / 86400 - pday, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

which may not give the result you expect. For example:

```
select to_date(last_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')) + 1 - 1 / 86400 - 0, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as test
from dual;
```

which gives me `31-JUL-2016` in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer but `31/07/0016` in PL/SQL Developer, due to different `nls_date_parameter` settings.

As Jon said, you need to clean up all of the date handling.